# how to include select-options parameter in function module

Tags: abap, function-module, sap-selection-screens

I have requirement where I need to fetch from - to (i.e the date value) values from select options to the function module. How do I declare these values in import parameter?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on what you are trying to achieve. What is the use case for this function module, where do you receive the range values from?

Comment: actually i need to create odata service using function module so my program contains sales office(VKBUR)  how will i declare from and to location in my function module?

Comment: I have to create a table type with SIGN OPTION LOW HIGH fields.. and i have declared it as                                                                                    lw_im_vkbur LIKE LINE OF im_vkbur will this work fine?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Type `RSIS_T_RANGE` directly for your import parameter in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

-Declare an importing parameter of type range of that date. Find out a standard tabletype for this from SE11
- Now when calling the FM, Pass the select option variable wilt[ ] brackets to the above parameter

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. I am actually new to programming plz can you just explain me how do i declare my work area... importing parameter is im_date and associated type i ve declared it as zdatecust and the line type for this zdatecust is zdatec(which includes type range)